# I seem to have an off-by-one error in the ListView.Row("Name", "Value") method of TestStack White

Tags: .net, nuget, white-framework, off-by-one

[image]

All I wish to do is right-click on the row where Name="2". So I use:

```
    ListView list = output.Get<ListView>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("selectorUser1"));

if (list.Items.Contains(keyName))

{

    ListViewRow lvr = list.Row("Name", keyName);
    lvr.Cells[0].RightClick();

}
```

If keyName= "2", it selects the row where Name="xxx" (i.e. an off-by-one issue). It makes me want to cry so much. The TestStack White dependencies have been brought in from nuget and I think they are version 4.x (?) or at least they should be up-to-date, I'm using .Net 4.5.1 but can drop down to 4.0 if needed. Interestingly, nuget package console warns:

> The names of some imported commands from the module 'TestStack.White'
>   include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To
>   find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command
>   again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type
>   Get-Verb.

Has anyone seen anything like this when using White?
I'm so at a loss here...

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView list = output.Get<ListView>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("selectorUser1"));

list.Rows.ForEach(p =>
    {
        if(p.Name == "Name")
        {
            p.Cells.ForEach(c =>
            {
                if(c.Text.ToString() == "2")
                {
                    c.RightClick();
                }

            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Appreciated- but this turns out to suffer from the same issue. I think i have solved the fundamental problem and will answer my own question. Thanks again.

Comment: Use UIAComWrapper : https://github.com/TestStack/White/tree/UIAComWrapper

Answer (score 0):

The answer *seems* to be- this is a bug on Windows 10 (only?). The exact same code works as intended on windows 7. Go figure.